# Exception when I make a text change in sqllite db file

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, exception

I have Html stored in sqllite db class, I need to update text of that html. When I make that change and run my application , I get the following exception. Not sure why the file is not getting created

```
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)   
2020-04-06 07:09:41.540 2082-3288/system_process E/SQLiteDatabase: DB wipe detected: package=com.exceed reason=corruption file=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.exceed/files/DataModel3.sqlite ctime=2020-04-06T03:09:41Z mtime=2020-04-06T03:09:41Z atime=2020-04-06T03:09:41Z checkfile [unable to obtain timestamp]
2020-04-06 07:09:41.540 2082-3288/system_process E/SQLiteDatabase: at java.lang.Throwable: STACKTRACE
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.wipeDetected(SQLiteDatabase.java:2741)
    at android.database.DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler.onCorruption(DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler.java:55)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.onCorruption(SQLiteDatabase.java:399)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:899)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:786)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:733)
    at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.returnDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:408)
    at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:401)
    at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:176)
    at com.exceed.uae.new_build.database.OpenHelper.<init>(OpenHelper.java:23)
    at com.exceed.uae.new_build.database.OpenHelper.getDatabase(OpenHelper.java:28)
    at com.exceed.uae.new_build.FcaApplication.onCreate(FcaApplication.java:92)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1182)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6460)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     2020-04-06 07:09:41.540 2082-3288/system_process E/SQLiteDatabase: DB wipe detected: package=com.exceed reason=corruption file=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.exceed/files/DataModel3.sqlite ctime=2020-04-06T03:09:41Z mtime=2020-04-06T03:09:41Z atime=2020-04-06T03:09:41Z checkfile [unable to obtain timestamp]
     2020-04-06 07:09:41.541 18613-18613/com.exceed E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler: deleting the database file: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.exceed/files/DataModel3.sqlite
     2020-04-06 07:09:41.542 18613-18613/com.exceed E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 36683 of [c255889bd9]

    2020-04-06 07:09:41.542 18613-18613/com.exceed E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:36683: (2) open(/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.exceed/files/DataModel3.sqlite) - 
    2020-04-06 07:09:41.544 18613-18613/com.exceed E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.exceed./files/DataModel3.sqlite'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:215)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:197)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:505)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:198)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:915)
    at android.database
```

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to make this change? It seems your database got corrupted and it could be caused by different reasons.

Comment: It a very long file. I am just changing 100.000 to 60,000 in static html for one of my scrrens. It just doesnt create when I make this change. When I roll back the change, it works again. :(

Comment: I have debugged and checked that copy is not happening but not sure why

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to make any changes to sqllite file in ios or android, we cant just directly change the sqllite file, it will give error. We need to download sqllite for db and then we can change the data by firing sql query.